# displaying network routing list in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, networking, ip

When i use "route print" from command line i get all data routing table. I need to get this same data in c#
[image: Data i need]

What i have tried is

```
            foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 || ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
                {
                    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                          //some code here
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Actually this code block gives some data but i need the all map like in the picture above. I need netmask,gateway,interface,metric etc..  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution i find is:
1)Adding System.Management.Automation package to the project
2)Adding this codeblock

```
     private string RunScript(string script)
        {
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
            pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject pSObject in results)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

i get data by running command line by hidden way.